# IOS Handwriting Recognition API?

Tags: ios

I am looking to create an IOS application that allows the user to 'write' on the iPhone/iPad device with their finger and have the software recognize the characters.

Does the base IOS API support this capability or are their royalty free libraries for IOS that support this?

Comment: Downscaling the question without an explanation has no value to me. Whoever did so, shore up your confidence and be kind enough to comment why.

Answer (score 1):

I work for MyScript, market leader in handwriting recognition and digital ink management technology. We offer handwriting recognition APIs. For more information, see http://dev.myscript.com/. Developer tools accessible on the site include a free, 90-day developer license.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this but I was looking for something along the lines in my comment to anhtu.

Comment: @Aprio And MyScript is impressive by the way but licensing issues have me looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Tesseract ORC** is good for recognize text base on training sets.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, this would be a port effort I suppose. I was looking to see if it were a native IOS API/Capability.